# How do I activate a macro for a project?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to develop a macro to send automated text messages through WhatsApp.

I already went on to "Options" under the "files" tab on Excel. I activated macros VBA which is not reccomended due to certain dangers. Whenever I try run a macro project a message pops-up informing me "the macros in the project are disabled".

What should I do?

This is what my macro looks like, could it be something on the macro itself?

```
Sub WebwhatsaApp()

'Activate silenium type library: tools > reference

Dim Bot As New WebDriver
Dim ks As New Keys

'Initiate new chrome instance & navigate to WebWhatsApp
Bot.Start "Chrome", "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
Bot.Get

'Ask user to scan QR Code. Once logged in continue with the macro
MsgBox "Please Scan the QR Code. After you are logged in please confirm this message by clicking"

'Determine number of messages by identifying number of last rows in column A
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



Stop


End Sub
```

Comment: Reopen the workbook and select Enable macros if it appears.

If it doesn't then close the file, right-click on the file in File Explorer and select properties. Place a checkmark in the unblock checkbox.

Comment: Excel > File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings > Enable VBA macros > OK

Comment: Welcome Iuan! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!